# Spacing the x-axis labels in Bokeh

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I have a lot of time labels on the x-axis, but at low zoom they are stuck together. I searched a lot but could not solve this problem.

[image]

Comment: You have left the values as strings so that is a categorical axis, not a datetime axis. You should convert the x values to be datetimes and use a proper datetime axis

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to bokeh. Can you provide a sample code?
@bigreddot

Comment: The docs cover this: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#datetime-axes